# Unable to link emacs.d directory

Tags: init-file, start-up, config

I moved `.emacs.d` folder from home directory to a folder called `dot_files` so that it will be easy to sync various dot files. From there I have linked it to home so that emacs can load that configuration files. But when I start emacs, it is throwing this warning and not loading it.

> Warning (initialization): Unable to create user-emacs-directory' (~/.emacs.d/).
>
> Any data that would normally be written there may be lost!
>
> If you never want to see this message again,
> customize the variable `user-emacs-directory-warning'.

How can I link emacs config so that it works normally?

Comment: When you say "link", what kind of link did you make? Can you post the output of `ls -la ~ | grep emacs`?

Comment: I have used `ln -s /source /target` to create link.

Comment: You have created symbolic link. Try hard link instead, that is, invoke `ln` without `-s` flag.

Comment: @Mark `ln: ‘anand/dotfiles/emacs.d’: hard link not allowed for directory`

Comment: There should be no need for a hard link. Symlinks usually work fine in this scenario. Perhaps there's a permissions issue?

Comment: It was permission error.

Comment: Very good. I've made that an answer, then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Symlinks usually work fine in this scenario, so that's unlikely to be a problem.

You should check the file and directory permissions.

Answer (score 0):

A patch which allows you to specify .emacs.d location via `EMACS_USER_DIRECTORY' environment variable is available in https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=15539 but it's not yet merged. This should eliminate the need for you to use symlinks.